# Fullscreen Li horizontal scrolling items not working properly

Tags: css

i am trying to create a responsive fullscreen horizontal gallery scroll.
i have worked it out but the results are not okay.
Actuallt the image should be fully strecthed to an li. i's vertically scrolling.
secondly the li's are not shoing fine on firefox, but on chrome it works fine.
please help.
thanks.
my code snippet

```
    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;          

        max-height: 100%;
        width: 25%;

    }
```

here is the fiddle 
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nH4ez/)

Thanks.

Comment: try to add max-height to img http://jsfiddle.net/nH4ez/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**demo with li.image = 25%**](http://jsfiddle.net/nH4ez/1/)

[**Full li image demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nH4ez/2/)

```
body {
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

you have missing `width` from `body tag`

Keep in mind that `width: 100%;` on `slides` class wont work unless the parent of this class has `width` defined in it (*which is body here*)!!

Comment: Thanks but still if i use another tall image in li the browser shows vertical scroller and i need the image to be completely fit. is there a way?

Comment: here is a live example.. . webcheck.co.in/sc/scroll.html

Comment: And there is still a small gap between li's . can you tell e why is that?

Comment: for starters...you forgot to put a `.` in the stylesheet for the `slides` class :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44302/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-marc-andre)

Comment: Hey man i will chat with you later. right now i am going somewhere. but thanks for the efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you li height is fixed, you can use img width as 100%

```
slides {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        li {
            display: inline-block;      
            height: 100px !imoprtant;
            width: 25%;
        }
        li img{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IWOmuXUz/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks but still if i use another tall image in li the browser shows vertical scroller and i need the image to be completely fit. is there a way?